# Trigger add with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsx

I want to add a trigger on the navbar toggle button when click a link with pure javascript. Not Jquery. I tried with this code but it's not working.

```
closeNavbar() {
        document.getElementById("collaspe-btn").addEventListener("click");
}

<Navbar.Toggle
    id="collaspe-btn"
/>

<Link
    to="features"
    onClick={this.closeNavbar}
>
```

Comment: you have added the listener but not doing any action on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger click event you can use `.click()` method. like,

```
closeNavbar() {
        document.getElementById("collaspe-btn").click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener accepts three parameters the first being the event, the other being a function that specifies the function to run when the event occurs and the third (optional) being a boolean value, which specifies whether the event should be executed in the capturing or in the bubbling phase.

```
document.getElementById("collaspe-btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    //do something
});
```

Or,

```
document.getElementById("collaspe-btn").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
function clickHandler(){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I want when the `<Link>` is clicked then trigger the `collaspe-btn`

Comment: In that case, you can do something like this,
`document.getElementById("collaspe-btn").click();` inside your closeNavBar function.